# MVC unsure how to retrieve related objects in a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I pass a viewmodel into view that looks like this

```
assessment
    questions   
        [0]
            QuestionText
            QuestionID
        [1]
            QuestionText
            QuestionID

    Answers
        [0]
            TheAnswer
            QuestionID
```

Basically my view has a list of questions and list of any answers that may have already chosen.

I need to display all the questions and any chosen answer
The link between question and answer is `QuestionID`

This is my razor code in the view which loops all the questions

```
@foreach (var question in Model.Assessment.Questions)
{
    <li class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            @Html.Raw(question.QuestionText)
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            @Html.Raw(<--No idea what to put here-->)
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

How can I retrieve the selected answer for the question?

EDIT

Here are my models

```
public class Assessment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime AssessmentDate { get; set; }
        public int AreaID { get; set; }

        public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public int DisplayNumber { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public string QuestionHelp { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int ProcessID { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Assessment> Assessment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

public class Answer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Assessment> Assessments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your model is not correct - you should have a collection of a model containing `QuestionID`, `QuestionText` and `TheAnswer`

Comment: Not exactly. I may have badly designed my model but the idea was that a question may have answers from many areas (areas are just my phase for a user). So for example, user1 may have an answer for question 1, and user2 may also have an answer for question 1. It that good design?

Comment: No (at least not the way you have shown). Not sure what is the relationship between `Assessment` and `Area`, but `Answer` needs properties `ID`, `TheAnswer` (is that `Value`?), `QuestionID` and `AreaID` (or UserID).

Comment: I have just seen you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436592/struggling-to-design-a-good-model-for-a-survey-assessment) and assuming this is still based on that db structure, the you already have all the data you need - you just need to create a view model with properties for `QuestionText` and `AnswerText` and for each `Question` and you can project the data into that view model

Comment: `Area` can have many `Assessments`. Yes it is based on that db structure. I'm not sure how to implement the view model you suggest. I have an `AssessmentViewModel` which contains the `Assessment`. The `Assessment` has a navigation property for `Answers` I presumed I could use to lookup the correct answer for the quesion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127484/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-totalitarian).

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Model.Assessment.chosenAnswers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionID == question.QuestionID)` and if it's not null show the respective field

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @foreach (var question in Model.Assessment.Questions)
{
    <li class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            @Html.Raw(question.QuestionText)
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
           @Html.Raw(Model.Assessment.chosenAnswers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionID == question.QuestionID))
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

Comment: That returns `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Answer_377871C1BD8495A0E37E4B78BF5734B6B866303FD05C7859A7528EC214605C08` I needed to add .Value to the end

Comment: @totalitarian Check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466424/how-can-i-solve-this-system-data-entity-dynamicproxies-error](Link)

Comment: Because you might have tried to display a whole object, but not its field. Actually, in this case you just need to choose your respective field with a necessary value. Something like that:  `Model.Assessment.chosenAnswers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.QuestionID == question.QuestionID).Value`. Though, sure, if you have an answer array inside your object, you should use it instead.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense